# $lookup with double nested array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

please, help I need to do $lookup/join for field pid in 2 level nested array where coll2.string(pid)==coll1.a.p.pid , collection coll1 is pretty big and there is index on "a.p.pid" but not sure how to do lookup on nested array elements and by chance to avoid $unwind and use the index "a.p.pid" ...

coll1:

```
[
  {
  a:[
     {
      p:[
         {pid:"1" ,date:"2022-01-22"},
         {pid:"4", date:"2022-01-25"}
       ]
     }
   ,{
     p:[
        {pid:"3",date:"2022-01-27"}
      ]
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

coll2:

```
 [ 
  {
   pid:1
  }
  ,
 {
  pid:3
  }
 ]
```

Expected result:

```
 [
  {pid:1, date:"2022-01-22"}
  {pid:3, date:"2022-01-27"}
 ]
```

collections sizes:

```
db.col2.count()
51171548
db.col1.count()
81039496
```

mongodb version 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why do you have to avoid using `$unwind`

```
db.col2.aggregate([
  {
    $set: { pid: { $toString: "$pid" } }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "col1",
      localField: "pid",
      foreignField: "a.p.pid",
      as: "date",
      let: { pid: "$pid" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $unwind: "$a"
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$a.p"
        },
        {
          $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$a.p.pid", "$$pid" ] } }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: { date: { $first: "$date.a.p.date" }, pid: { $toInt: "$pid" } }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FZ9g04QbgEk)

---

```
db.col2.aggregate([
  {
    $set: { pid: { $toString: "$pid" } }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "col1",
      localField: "pid",
      foreignField: "a.p.pid",
      as: "date"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      date: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$date",
          as: "d1",
          cond: {
            $gt: [
              {
                $size: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$d1.a",
                    as: "d2",
                    cond: {
                      $gt: [
                        {
                          $size: {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$$d2.p",
                              as: "d3",
                              cond: { $eq: [ "$$d3.pid", "$pid" ] }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: { date: { $first: "$date.a" } }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "date": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$date",
          as: "d2",
          cond: {
            $gt: [
              {
                $size: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$d2.p",
                    as: "d3",
                    cond: { $eq: [ "$$d3.pid", "$pid" ] }
                  }
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: { date: { $first: "$date.p" } }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      date: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$date",
          as: "d3",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$d3.pid", "$pid" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      date: { $first: "$date.date" },
      pid: { $toInt: "$pid" }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-BgCetHvp88)

Comment: collection is relatively big and initial 2x unwinds on col1  always take alot of time , but your solution provide me the help I needed , thanks alot!

Comment: any option to avoid the 2x unwinds  or some initial filtering for col1 based on the index "$a.p.pid" is highly appreciated

Comment: also can't understand why I cannot add one more of same  $match stage in the beginning of the  lookup pipeline so I reduce the amount of documents to unwind ...

Comment: another question arise: Can the $unwind/$unwind/$match be replaced with $map/$filter that maybe using the index?

Comment: @R2D2 What kind of `$match` stage you want to add in the beginning of the lookup pipeline. I think `$unwind/$unwind/$match` can be replaced with `$map/$filter` but not sure it will use the index or not.

Comment: the same $match stage but is not working just to reduce the amount of documents for unwind :  $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$a.p.pid", "$$pid" ] } }

Comment: @R2D2 Since we have `localField: "pid", foreignField: "a.p.pid"` , I don't think we need to add `$match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$a.p.pid", "$$pid" ] } }`  in the beginning of the lookup pipeline. It is the same thing right ?

Comment: for v.4.0 not working , I had to remove the locaFiled/ForeignField

Comment: @R2D2 I see. That may be a big problem. I would try another method.

Comment: @R2D2 I update my answer by replace `$unwind/$unwind/$match` with `$map/$filter`. Not sure it is fast enough. Try it and tell me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242597/discussion-between-r2d2-and-yuting).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution implemented in the real case confirmed to work correctly in v.4.0:

```
 db.col2.aggregate([
 {
 $project: {
  pid: {
    $toString: "$pid"
  }
 }
 },
  {
   $lookup: {
    from: "col1",
    localField: "pid",
    foreignField: "a.p.pid",
    as: "date"
  }
 },
 {
  $project: {
  "date.a.p.date": 1,
  "date.a.p.pid": 1,
  _id: 1,
  pid: 1
 }
 },
 {
  $unwind: "$date"
 },
 {
   $unwind: "$date.a"
 },
 {
   $unwind: "$date.a.p"
 },
 {
 $project: {
   pid: "$date.a.p.pid",
   date: "$date.a.p.date",
   "matched": {
    "$eq": [
      "$pid",
      "$date.a.p.pid"
    ]
  }
 }
 },
  {
   $match: {
     matched: true
  }
 },
  {
   $project: {
    "_id": 0,
    pid: 1,
   date: 1
  }
 }
 ])
```

@YuTing: Your answer marked as accepted since it seems better for higher versions!
Tanks to @YuTing for the help!

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3EYn8HeGoSO)