# MongoDB how to find all documents who's array contains a specific string?

Tags: java, mongodb

Below is an example of my "Event" document in MongoDB. I want to be able to query all of the Event documents where the attendees array contains "623d03730e82c57fefa52fb2" (a user ID).

Here is one of my event documents:

```
_id: ObjectId(623ce74372a28f08dea6c959)
description: "Fun BBQ to celebrate my 21st!"
host: "623d03730e82c57fefa52fb2"
invitees: Array
location: "My address..."
name: "Fun Birthday BBQ"
private: true
date: "03/28/22"
end: "11:15 PM"
start: "06:35 PM"
attendees:Array
   0: "623d03730e82c57fefa52fb2"
```

Here is my broken query code:

```
    String id = "623d03730e82c57fefa52fb2";
    // I have also tried Document queryFilter = new Document("attendees", id);
    Document queryFilter = new Document("attendees", new Document("$in", Arrays.asList(id)));
```

The above code always returns an empty result. To clarify I am using Java and MongoDB Realms but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Does the `attendees` array contain string or ObjectId types?

Comment: That ended up being the issue @rickhg12hs !! Turns out using string and ObjectID interchangeably in code and database can cause some weird errors

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `$in`, use only `$eq` is ok.

```
db.collection.find({
  attendees: "623d03730e82c57fefa52fb2"
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A-vBouEuim9)

Comment: Sadly this does not seem to work as I just get back an empty list of documents. Maybe something else is influencing the results?

Comment: @Lolzar Edit your own question with the data you try and show us your expected result as a valid JSON document. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71343267/lookup-with-double-nested-array-elements/71345533#71345533) question.

Answer (score 0):

For easier and more efficient queries, it's important that the types of field values remain consistent.

For example, if `"_id"` is stored at an `ObjectId`, then query parameters should also be of type `ObjectId`.  Likewise, if they are strings, then consistently use strings.

If different value types are stored for individual field values, successful queries can still be possible, but not as efficiently since the field types must be considered in the queries.  For example, if trying to `find` a doc by a field that may have a string or an `ObjectId` type, the query must either search for both types, or the query writer must know the type beforehand.  It's easier and more efficient to just pick one type for a field and stick to it.